# Can somebody explain what is the role of URLPermission class in Java 1.8 in client server architecture

Tags: java, java-8, java-security

When I was going through the Java 1.8 features, I came across `java.net.URLPermission` class.I didn't get much documentation on the usage of this library can some body help with a working code for this class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This class is used by [security manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) to control HTTP URL permissions. For example

```
grant codebase "example.jar" {
    // allow only GET requests http://www.example.com
    permission java.net.URLPermission 
        "http://www.example.com", "GET";
};
```

You can find more info in [`JEP-184`](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/184) and [`java.net.URLPermission`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLPermission.html) javadoc.

Comment: That sounds good .Thanks for the information will check with JEP-184 documentation.